# How to zoom in into an environment texture ?

Tags: camera, lighting

I chose **cycles render** as the render engine, 
went into the **world panel**, 
clicked in the **surface part** onto **use nodes** 
and selected from **color** environment texture.

Now when I am in the rendered mode of **viewport shading**, 
I can see the texture environment and it lights my glossy
cube as it should be, but when I scroll the mouse-wheel, 
the size of the cube changes and the size of the environment texture
stays the same.

*How can I achieve to move with a camera inside this environment texture and zoom into parts of it?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a node "coordinate texture" to environment texture and scale only "X" and "Y"